# unreadable characters http response

Tags: java, http, post, character

Help me please. 
I make http post request in java to http://ind-kod.org.ua/cgi-bin/decodecode.cgi?c=3255101113- for example.
After, I receive response. Response has unreadable characters

#### РќРµРјРЅРѕРіРѕ Рѕ РІРЅРµС€С‚Р°С‚РЅРѕРј

Response i see in console.

What should i do that i can read response correctly? Thank you very much.

My PC-Windows 7(64 bit), Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Build id: 20150219-0600

This is my Java code.

```
        final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
    // http://ind-kod.org.ua/cgi-bin/decodecode.cgi?c=3255101113

    URL url = new URL("http://ind-kod.org.ua/cgi-bin/decodecode.cgi");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/html");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);


    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
            conn.getOutputStream());

    writer.write("c=3255101113");
    writer.flush();



    InputStream gzippedResponse = conn.getInputStream();
    GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(gzippedResponse);
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(gis);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

    String readed;
    String line;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    while ((readed = reader.readLine()) != null) {

        response.append(readed);
    }
    writer.close();
    reader.close();

    System.out.println(response.toString());
```

This is my response.

```html
</head>
<body bgcolor=#00eeff text=#000000>

<table border=0 align=center cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width=800px>
<tr><td style="border: solid 1px #ffffff; background: #cccccc;">


<table border=0 align=center cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width=100%>
<tr><td>

<!-- Ukrainian Banner Network 160С…60 START -->
<center><script>
//<!--
user = "74694";
page = "2";
pid = Math.round((Math.random() * (10000000 - 1)));
document.write("<iframe src='http://banner.kiev.ua/cgi-bin/bi.cgi?h" +
user + "&amp;"+ pid + "&amp;" + page + "&amp;5' frameborder=0 vspace=0 hspace=0 " +
" width=160 height=60 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 scrolling=no>");
document.write("<a href='http://banner.kiev.ua/cgi-bin/bg.cgi?" +
user + "&amp;"+ pid + "&amp;" + page + "&amp;5' target=_top>");
document.write("<img border=0 src='http://banner.kiev.ua/" +
"cgi-bin/bi.cgi?i" + user + "&amp;" + pid + "&amp;" + page +
"&amp;5' width=160 height=60 alt='Ukrainian Banner Network'></a>");
document.write("</iframe>");
//-->
</script><br>
<small><a href=http://banner.kiev.ua/ target=_top>РЈРєСЂР°РёРЅСЃРєР°СЏ Р‘Р°РЅРЅРµСЂРЅР°СЏ РЎРµС‚СЊ</a></small>
</center>
<!-- Ukrainian Banner Network 160С…60 END -->
</td>
<td>
<!-- Ukrainian Banner Network 468x60 START -->
<center><script>
//<!--
user = "74694";
page = "2";
pid = Math.round((Math.random() * (10000000 - 1)));
document.write("<iframe src='http://banner.kiev.ua/cgi-bin/bi.cgi?h" +
user + "&amp;"+ pid + "&amp;" + page + "' frameborder=0 vspace=0 hspace=0 " +
" width=468 height=60 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 scrolling=no>");
document.write("<a href='http://banner.kiev.ua/cgi-bin/bg.cgi?" +
user + "&amp;"+ pid + "&amp;" + page + "' target=_top>");
document.write("<img border=0 src='http://banner.kiev.ua/" +
"cgi-bin/bi.cgi?i" + user + "&amp;" + pid + "&amp;" + page +
"' width=468 height=60 alt='РЈРєСЂР°РёРЅСЃРєР°СЏ Р‘Р°РЅРЅРµСЂРЅР°СЏ РЎРµС‚СЊ'></a>");
document.write("</iframe>");
//-->
</script><br>
<small><a href=http://banner.kiev.ua/ target=_top>РЈРєСЂР°РёРЅСЃРєР°СЏ Р‘Р°РЅРЅРµСЂРЅР°СЏ РЎРµС‚СЊ</a></small>
</center>
<!-- Ukrainian Banner Network 468x60 END -->
</td>
<td>
<!-- Ukrainian Banner Network 160С…60 START -->
<center><script>
//<!--
user = "74694";
page = "2";
pid = Math.round((Math.random() * (10000000 - 1)));
document.write("<iframe src='http://banner.kiev.ua/cgi-bin/bi.cgi?h" +
user + "&amp;"+ pid + "&amp;" + page + "&amp;5' frameborder=0 vspace=0 hspace=0 " +
" width=160 height=60 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 scrolling=no>");
document.write("<a href='http://banner.kiev.ua/cgi-bin/bg.cgi?" +
user + "&amp;"+ pid + "&amp;" + page + "&amp;5' target=_top>");
document.write("<img border=0 src='http://banner.kiev.ua/" +
"cgi-bin/bi.cgi?i" + user + "&amp;" + pid + "&amp;" + page +
"&amp;5' width=160 height=60 alt='Ukrainian Banner Network'></a>");
document.write("</iframe>");
//-->
</script><br>
<small><a href=http://banner.kiev.ua/ target=_top>РЈРєСЂР°РёРЅСЃРєР°СЏ Р‘Р°РЅРЅРµСЂРЅР°СЏ РЎРµС‚СЊ</a></small>
</center>
<!-- Ukrainian Banner Network 160С…60 END -->
</td></tr>
</table>

</td></tr>
</table>

<br>

<center>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "pub-5530741219705142";
/* 728x15, СЃРѕР·РґР°РЅРѕ 13.07.09 */
google_ad_slot = "1332980612";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 15;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
</center>

<br>

<table border=0 align=center cellspacing=0 cellpadding=5 width=800px>
<tr><td style="border: solid 1px #ff0000; font-size: 20px; background: #ff9999;">Р’РЅРёРјР°РЅРёРµ, РёРЅС„РѕСЂРјР°С†РёСЏ РѕСЂРёРµРЅС‚РёСЂРѕРІР°РЅР° РЅР° РіСЂР°Р¶РґР°РЅ РЈРєСЂР°РёРЅС‹!</td></tr>
</table>
<br>

<table border=0 align=center cellspacing=0 cellpadding=5 width=800px>
<tr><td style="border: solid 1px #007700; background: #00ccff; vertical-align: t
op;">

<p style="text-align: right;">РЎСЃС‹Р»РєР° <b>РґСЂСѓРіСѓ</b> <a href="http://ind-kod.org.ua/">http://ind-kod.org.ua/</a></p>

<h2>Р РµР·СѓР»СЊС‚Р°С‚</h2>
<b>Р”Р°С‚Р° СЂРѕР¶РґРµРЅРёСЏ: <u>13.02.1989</u>, РїРѕР» <u>Рњ</u></b>

<br>
<br>

<hr>

<h3>РќРµРјРЅРѕРіРѕ Рѕ РІРЅРµС€С‚Р°С‚РЅРѕРј</h3>
<p>РњРѕСЏ СЃРѕС‚СЂСѓРґРЅРёС†Р° СЃ РєРѕРґРѕРј <a href="/cgi-bin/decodecode.cgi?c=3127600040">31276<i>000</i>4<i>0</i></a> СѓС‚РІРµСЂР¶РґР°РµС‚ С‡С‚Рѕ РµРµ РґР°С‚Р° СЂРѕР¶РґРµРЅРёСЏ <b>17</b>.08.1985, РїСЂРё СЌС‚РѕРј РґР°РЅРЅР°СЏ С„РѕСЂРјР° РІС‹РІРѕРґРёС‚ СЂРµР·СѓР»СЊС‚Р°С‚ "<b>18</b>.08.1985", РґРѕРїРѕР»РЅРёС‚РµР»СЊРЅР°СЏ РїСЂРѕРІРµСЂРєР° С‚РѕР¶Рµ РґР°РµС‚ СЂРµР·СѓР»СЊС‚Р°С‚ "<b>18</b>.08.1985". РњРѕС‘ РјРЅРµРЅРёРµ - СЃРѕС‚СЂСѓРґРЅРёРєРё РЅР°Р»РѕРіРѕРІРѕР№ РґРѕРїСѓСЃС‚РёР»Рё РѕС€РёР±РєСѓ РїСЂРё С„РѕСЂРјРёСЂРѕРІР°РЅРёРё РєРѕРґР°.</p>
<!-- p>Р•СЃР»Рё РІС‹ РїРѕР»СѓС‡РёР»Рё РЅРµ РїСЂР°РІРёР»СЊРЅС‹Р№ СЂРµР·СѓР»СЊС‚Р°С‚, Рё РЅР° РІСЃРµ 100 СѓРІРµСЂРµРЅС‹ С‡С‚Рѕ РґР°С‚Р° Рё РєРѕРґ РІРµСЂРЅС‹ - РЅР°РїРёС€РёС‚Рµ РїРѕР¶Р°Р»СѓР№СЃС‚Р° Рѕ С‚РѕРј <a href="mailto:pasha_pv@ukr.net?subject=decodecode">РјРЅРµ</a>. РЇ Р±СѓРґСѓ СЂРµРіРёСЃС‚СЂРёСЂРѕРІР°С‚СЊ С‚Р°РєРёРµ СЃР»СѓС‡Р°Рё РЅР° СЌС‚РѕР№ СЃС‚СЂР°РЅРёС†Рµ СЃ С†РµР»СЊСЋ РґРѕРЅРµСЃС‚Рё РїРѕР»СЊР·РѕРІР°С‚РµР»СЏРјРё РјР°РєСЃРёРјР°Р»СЊРЅСѓСЋ РѕР±СЉРµРєС‚РёРІРЅРѕСЃС‚СЊ.</p -->

</td></tr>
</table>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to set the character encoding of the input stream; you're currently using platform default - which is likely different to the encoding of the gzipped content. How you work out the correct encoding is a different question - you need to examine the `Content-Type` header.

Comment: Ok. Thanks, i will try/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the character encoding of the input stream; you're currently using platform default - which is likely different to the encoding of the gzipped content. How you work out the correct encoding is a different question - you need to examine the Content-Type header.

Thank you! Your answer help me.

Change

```
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(gis);
```

To

```
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(gis,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: This is **not correct**. You need to get the encoding _from the response_ - by reading the header. You cannot just assume `UTF-8`.